# AD application note MT-097

Tags: pcb, emc, transmission-line, microwave, signal-integrity

Below is the statement from AD application note [MT-097](https://www.analog.com/media/en/training-seminars/tutorials/mt-097.pdf).
[image]

I have see this explanation many places.

**But no one explains how transmission line effects comes when rise time is smaller than 2*times propagation delay
and how transmission line effect disappears when 2*times propagation delay is less than rise time.**

Can someone please explain this.

EDIT#1

I found an explanation [here](https://resources.altium.com/p/key-elements-high-speed-pcb-design).Which explains what will happen to reflections when Rt>2Tpd and Rt<2Tpd.

[image]

Comment: Updated the question.Could you please check.

Answer (score 3):

> *But no one explains how transmission line effects comes when rise time
> is smaller than 2 times propagation delay and how transmission line
> effect disappears when 2 times propagation delay is less than rise
> time.*

It isn't an either/or situation; transmission line effects happen on really slow signals but, they are negligible when the lines are short and, become less negligible as the line gets longer. At some point, the effects are generally regarded as problematic and, the ADI quote is trying to "define" that "debateable" point.

In other words it's a rule of thumb (or guide) that "suggests" the point where you **should** consider adding a termination resistor to prevent reflections causing (for example) data signal corruption.

An alternative (but largely equivalent) rule of thumb considers the frequency spectrum; if the wavelength of the highest frequency of a transmission is less than ten times the cable length, then you should consider using a termination resistor.

For analogue signal transmission, reflections can "appear" to cause strange impedances that can result in a signal failing to reach an intermediary destination at the required amplitude (another example).

But, both these types of effect aren't suddenly switched-on at a certain line length or rise time.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few rules of thumb that you may or may not be aware of that are in use. One of them is the relation between signal bandwidth and rise time an goes something like this : BW ≈ 0.35/Tr.
Now there's another lesser known yet similar rule of thumb that roughly gives the propagation delay in a rough relation to the signal bandwidth and is sometimes given as : T ≈ 0.7/BW.
From this you can roughly see that T ≈ 2Tr. This is very simplified and highly dependent of specifics of both the signal type and the transmission line ...
So transmission line effects will be observed if we have T ≥ 2Tr as a ball park, and these will be very evident as some already mentioned if T >> 2Tr.

Presumably AD took the value where T ≤ ½Tr as a definitely safe and good guide for no transmission line effects observable, but some might argue that it needs to be more like T ≤ ¼Tr or lower depending on the type of signals ... Again it is a rule of thumb and should only be taken as that and probably confirmed with real measurements, using real signals and real transmission lines ...

Comment: I agree,but how that transmission line effect comes in if Tr less than 2Tpd.

Comment: @Hari I suggest looking into a visual, animated simulation of a pulse travelling down a transmission line. There are some Matlab simulations available, and there is that BOUNCE.exe (or java version) that simulates and shows in real-time the reflections etc. Not sure though if it does pulses, but it does standing-waves ... It may be useful to look at what happens when the tx-line is very short, long and very long (and conversely  when Tprop is short long and very long, as speed and delay are related for a fixed tx length) to see what happens visually, with/without a termination ...

Answer (score 1):

The factor of 2 in the rule of thumb comes from the fact that 2·T<sub>pd</sub> is the time it takes for a signal to reach the receiving end of the transmission line (1·T<sub>pd</sub>) and then for a reflected signal to return to the driver (another 1·T<sub>pd</sub>, for a total of 2·T<sub>pd</sub>). It's the point at which the driver starts having to fight against its own reflected signal.

This is only a rule of thumb, because even at slower rise and fall times, the driver will still have to fight reflections; it's just that the difference between the driver's output and the reflected voltage reaches its maximum at T<sub>r/f</sub> < 2·T<sub>pd</sub>.

Adding an impedance-matched termination eliminates reflections.

Comment: I am aware of the rule of thumb.Can you please explain how reflection happen in a transmission line when rise time is smaller than 2*times propagation delay .

Comment: @Hari Reflection always happens in a transmission line regardless of the qualities of a signal, unless the transmission line is terminated with its characteristic impedance. I am attempting to explain that the reflection is where the factor of 2 in the rule of thumb comes from.